# A standard form for declaration of authorship shares inside an author collective

Tags: authorship, publications

I need a formal agreement from co-authors of our publication describing their individual authorship contribution. In other words, I need a form (signed by all authors) that state the contribution in percents of all authors of the given publication.

I tried to find some kind of a standard letter/contract/form for this purpose, however I have not find anything.

I guess I can create letter like this by myself (containing: name/doi of the publication, author names with perceptual contribution (and explanation what does it mean), date and signatures).

Can anyone recommend a template I can adapt for this purposes? I guess some institutions have a dedicated form for this.

*You can stop reading here.*

Simplified explanation why I need that:

1. The research funding in my country (or at least some part of it) is strongly dependable on the results of research institutions. When two or more institutions publish together, they have to claim their percentual contribution, so the funding can be allocated in the corresponding way.
2. Some institutions in my country reflect this shares also when they count employee merit (to offer promotion, or adjust salary...)

I guess this is issue in every country that tries to evaluate results and research in a fair way. If they do not do it, they most likely just divide 100% by number of authors - that also happen here, if you do not provide the form that states the shares otherwise.

Comment: Someplace like CERN might need to manage huge sets of authors formally.

Comment: I've never heard of an institution trying to quantify contributions as a percentage.  What do you need this for?

Comment: @NateEldredge I provided explanation in my question (it is a bit long).

Comment: So the contributions have to be in percentages?  It can't be of the form "Author A set up the experiments, Author B made the measurements, Author C did the data analysis"?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Exactly. Funding provider likes the actual shares instead of the abstractly described uncountable contributions. It is a specific case of research evaluation I guess.